# Url factory - google duplicate page- 301 redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am new to this site hope my issue is asked the right way.

To avoid urls with lots of ?id=11 etc. etc. for SEO purposes I build an urls that allowed me to have those urls rebuild in this way:

```
http://www.example.com/blah-blah-blah-blah/
```

Now I changed some of these urls so I needed to 301 redirect the old ones to the new ones with .htaccess. Problem is that when I redirect one of these the ?id=(+ number) is added:

```
example: url to redirect /blah-blah-blah-blah/ 

example: url redirected to /blah-blah-blah-blah/?id=11
```

The function that does the job is this:

```
function _prepare_url_text($string)
{

    //remove all characters that aren't  a-z, 0-9, dash, underscore or space

     $NOT_acceptable_characters_regex = '#[^-a-zA-Z0-9_ ]#';
     $string = preg_replace($NOT_acceptable_characters_regex, '', $string);

     //remove all leaidng and trailing spaces
     $string = trim($string);

      //change all dashed, underscores and psaces to dashe
     $string = preg_replace('#[-_ ]+#', '-', $string);

     //return the modified string
    return $string;

     }

     //buld a link that contains Type a Name

    function make_name_url($IDName, $ID)

     {
     // prepare le type name and acc name for inlcusion in URL
     $clean_ID_name = _prepare_url_text($AccName);

     //build the keyword reach url
     $url = SITE_DOMAIN . '/blah-blah-blah-blah-' . $clean_ID_name . '-A' . $ID . '/';

             //return the url
            return $url;
            }
```

The problem with all this is that Google thinks now that there are two copies of the same page. Could anyone help me understand what I can do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a canonical tag to your pages. This will stop duplicates.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en

Comment: How can this be done if all pages use the same page that displays different content?

Comment: http://bryanhadaway.com/super-simple-dynamic-canonical-link-code/ can communicate it far better than I can :)